# How to launch main activity of one application from another application on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 applications A & B. A has one activity. B has two activities. In B, one is the main (launcher) activity and the other is the default activity. All this is defined in the manifest file. 
But how do I launch the main activity of B from A ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this

```
     Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
     startActivity(launchIntent);`
```

Comment: Yes. It works. Can you please provide me a link to the documentation for the resources you used ?

Comment: @probuddhasingha http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Building